# Migrate to Git but a local Git repo already has changes (push fails)

Tags: git, svn, push

We are working on Git but there was no central repository before. We have moved ahead (3 months) now our client has created a repository on stash but its 3 months old code. I tried to create the local scenario on my machine before trying it on stash. Created a svn repository (S), moved it to git repository (G). now another git folder(G2) has already same file with different content. and when i try to push G2 to G, it says you cannot push it as remote contains work that you do not have locally. we cannot pull and push because it is way too much work now. and we have lot in the history as well.  i have tried push --force as well. didn't work either.

Comment: I found the answer here, it worked for me. http://eatmyrandom.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-merge-two-independent-git.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

force pushing is disabled by default (because it can be dangerous), you can ask your customer to enable it for a little time
he has to write in cli

```
$ git config --system receive.denyNonFastForwards false
```

Comment: Using `--system` is unlikely to work. Usually the individual repositories have `receive.denyNonFastForwards` disabled; the individual repo's config has higher precedence than the system config files. Instead, run the same command without `--system` from within the repository in question.

Comment: thanks i have been able to push my changes but unfortunately it has overwritten the previous history with the G2 history and i cannot see anything beyond the work started in december.

Comment: that is what i meant when told 'it can be dangerous', thought you understand this (force means overide)

Comment: i am just a rookie :) so what do you suggest how to go about it.

Comment: as you said your remote repo was overwritten, you can try to recover it if you have some other clone of thi repo, also you can try to use  'git reflog' to see the changes that was made and try to checkout to the right commit before pushing

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of configuration. As mentioned in a comment, the setting `receive.denyNonFastForwards` in a remote repository determines whether `git push --force` works. If that setting is active, you can still try deleting and then re-creating the remote branch (e.g. `git push --delete origin master; git push origin master`) – deleting branches is controlled by a different setting. Of course, doing this violates the spirit of `denyNonFastForwards` and you should check back with the owner of the repository before doing something like this.